# Excel / Google Sheets sum of product quantity by product & month

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to process a dataset that has the following format :

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgrbb.jpg)

What I want to do is to create a table containing on a row all the unique months of the dataset, and on one column all the unique products.

Afterwards, in that table I want to generate the sum of the quantity of every product for each month.

The result should be like so :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlyxT.jpg)

I managed to create the table but with the product names placed on a row and month names on a column and since there's more products than months I need to switch it.

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a pivot table?

Comment: Yeah I pivot table works just fine. I was looking for a formula to generate this table since the dataset's size often changes and I'm too lazy to create a pivot table every time it changes. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use pivot created from Table (in Table format not Range). In that case you do not have to change pivot settings (like range of source data) every time the dataset changes (just refresh) .